# Why Am I Getting Inconsistent LEFT JOIN Results in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, mysql-5.6, query

**Background**

I have a database in 3 different locations with the same exact static data (nothing updates it, it was a one-time import from another system).  In 2 of the 3 locations, a query similar to the following works fine (table and field names changed):

```
SELECT
  cr.E_ID
, cr.R_ID
, GROUP_CONCAT(csp.SP_ID) AS sp_ids
, GROUP_CONCAT(sp.SP_Type) AS sp_types
FROM db.TableA cr 
   LEFT JOIN db.TableB csp ON cr.R_ID = csp.R_ID
   LEFT JOIN db.TableC sp ON csp.SP_ID = sp.E_ID
WHERE cr.E_Id IN (12345)
GROUP BY cr.E_ID, cr.R_ID;
```

The result for a few lines should look something like this

```
E_ID   R_ID   sp_ids          sp_types
12345  7777   NULL            NULL
12345  7778   333,444,555     AC,CB,LW
12345  7779   666,777,888     CB,CB,LW
12345  7780   111,222,223     AC,AC,CB
12345  7781   NULL            NULL
```

So what's happening in the one environment is that the result looks something like this (most of the GROUP_CONCAT() information is NULL'd out, with only a few lines having maybe 1 match

```
E_ID   R_ID   sp_ids          sp_types
12345  7777   NULL            NULL
12345  7778   NULL            NULL
12345  7779   666             CB
12345  7780   NULL            NULL
12345  7781   NULL            NULL
```

I confirmed the table row counts match and, for matching rows, the IDs all exist.  I also did things like ANALYZE TABLE to no avail.

The explain plan is showing a full index scan on the intermediary table TableB as well as a GROUP operator just before the result is returned with a "tmp table/filesort".  The other two environments show the same exact explain plan output yet they are working fine.

```
select_type  table  type    possible_keys     key       key_len  ref        rows   extra
SIMPLE       cr     ref     ix__E_ID          ix__E_ID  5        const      12     Using index;Using temporary; Using filesort
SIMPLE       csp    index                     ix__SP_ID 4                   77489  Using where;Using index;Using join buffer (block nested loop)
SIMPLE       sp     eq_ref  PRIMARY,ix__E_ID  PRIMARY   4        csp.SP_ID  1
```

I found the following global variables to be different between the "broken" and "working" environments

```
PARAM              BROKEN ENV VAL       WORKING ENV VAL
aurora_lab_mode    ON                   OFF
back_log           450                  900
binlog_checksum    CRC32                NONE
binlog_format      STATEMENT            ROW
event_scheduler    OFF                  ON
innodb_buffer_pool_instances 4          8
innodb_buffer_pool_size 20090716160     46017806336
innodb_print_all_deadlocks OFF          ON
innodb_purge_batch_size 300             900
innodb_purge_threads 1                  3
innodb_read_io_threads 8                16
log_bin            OFF                  ON
max_connections    2000                 6000
query_cache_size   1116163072           2556593152
table_open_cache_instances 8            16
thread_cache_size  26                   61
```

**WorkAround**

I found a work around.  I added an index on cr.R_ID and csp.R_ID and after that the query results return as expected.  If I drop the indexes, the query results break again.

After indexes are applied the plan looks like this

```
select_type  table  type    possible_keys     key       key_len  ref        rows   extra
SIMPLE       cr     ref     ix__E_ID          ix__E_ID  5        const      12     Using where;Using index
SIMPLE       csp    ref     ix__R_ID          ix__R_ID  4        cr.R_ID    1.     Using index
SIMPLE       sp     eq_ref  PRIMARY,ix__E_ID  PRIMARY   4        csp.SP_ID  1
```

I also noticed that switching from a LEFT JOIN to an INNER JOIN displays the correct results for rows that have data in the joined tables but since we need every row for the provided ID in the resultset I had to switch it back to LEFT JOIN.

**Question**

Although I've found a work around, why this is happening?

It's very unnerving that a missing index can alter the resultset of a query, not just affect the query performance.  If it's happening here I'm betting this is happening elsewhere and I just don't know it yet.

MySQL version is Aurora 5.6.10.  Please let me know what other information I can add that would be useful in answering this question.
All tables are created using ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to my own problem and wanted to share here so anyone else that encounters this scenario will know the reason for the problem.

I tracked it down to the parameter group option of **aurora_lab_mode**.  When this option was turned off in that environment the unexpected query result behavior stopped.  I was able to verify this by turning it on and off again to verify the behavior.

I've since turned it off indefinitely.

This appears to have been fixed in Aurora 2.02 (MySQL v5.7.12) according to this [fix list](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Updates.MySQLBugs.html) page